# Regex capture only symbols

Tags: google-bigquery

Anyone know the appropriate Regex to grab any symbols (such as . / _ etc). I'm trying to extract anything that doesn't look like 1-3 complete words.

```
Online Chat
http://mailserver.test.com/zjalLNG391Vkfalka0
social
test.com
poc_email_outbound~51-tester-test~2018-04-12
http://mailserver.test.com/u/130931jiojf101901
```

to grab only the below:

```
http://mailserver.test.com/zjalLNG391Vkfalka0
test.com
poc_email_outbound~51-tester-test~2018-04-12
http://mailserver.test.com/u/130931jiojf101901
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_CONTAINS(line, r'[./_]')`

See example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Online Chat' line UNION ALL
  SELECT 'http://mailserver.test.com/zjalLNG391Vkfalka0' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'social' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'poc_email_outbound~51-tester-test~2018-04-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'http://mailserver.test.com/u/130931jiojf101901' 
)
SELECT line
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(line, r'[./_]')
```

To exclude all non-word characters you can use `REGEXP_CONTAINS(line, r'\W')`, which is equivalent to `REGEXP_CONTAINS(line, r'[^0-9A-Za-z_]')`
You can extend the latter with more chars that you want to exclude from criteria

Comment: Just to add some links that may be useful for other users too, in the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) you have the reference for using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` and several other regular expression functions. Additionally, you should know that BigQuery uses the re2 library in order to provide regex, so you can have a look at [its documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) in order to know more about it too.